# Salesforce1 Offline Cache

Tags: salesforce1-app, cache, offline

I have a requirement to cache some custom object data in Salesforce1 offline that will only be accessed in emergency situations (1-3x/year). From my understanding  Offline mode only works for recently viewed items and the recently viewed items are only held for 90 days.

the question is: is there a way I can programmatically "trick" salesforce into making the items recently viewed for a group of users and that I can schedule this to run once every 90 days?

Comment: You could probably put some code on the home page which accesses them. Then they would always be "recently viewed". I haven't tried it so I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: thanks, I gave that a go and it worked. It still requires the user to login to the app and cache the data under settings but they don't have to worry about whats under the "Recently viewed" items as the code took care of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include some code in your home page that accesses these records. Then they will be recently viewed for anyone who logs in.